# Linking custom headers in gcc compiler

Tags: c, gcc

I'm having trouble getting a program to compile.  The program's headers are

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stlib.h>
#include "useCurses.h"
#include "robotModel.h"
#include "maze.h"
```

I've tried compiling with

> gcc -I/path/to/folder program.c -o program.exe -lncurses

And get the following error messages:

> undefined reference to (function)

for each function called in program.c which is included in either robotModel.h or maze.h.
The files maze.h and robotModel.h both contain prototypes for functions which are defined  in files maze.c and robotModel.c, all of which are in the same folder as program.c. What am I forgetting to do here?

Edit: 
robotModel.h:

```
#ifndef ROBOTMODEL_H
#define ROBOTMODEL_H
(function prototypes)
#endif
```

robotModel.c:

```
#include "robotModel.h"
(function definitions, no main())
```

maze.h:

```
#ifndef MAZE_H
#define MAZE_H

#include "robotModel.h"
(function prototypes)
#endif
```

maze.c:

```
#include "maze.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
(function definitions, no main())
```

The compiler error points to every instance when a function defined in either maze.h or robotmodel.h is called in main() or another function in program.c.

Edit 2: I got it to work by using

> gcc program.c maze.c robotModel.c -o program.exe -lncurses

Comment: You should compile `maze.c, robotModel.c` source files as well.

Comment: Could you please post `useCurses.h`, `robotModel.h`, `maze.h`, and the relevant lines that the compiler error points to?

Answer (score 0):

You should compile `maze.c`, `robotModel.c` source files as well. –  Mahesh